# jquery form validate not throwing errors or submitting

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

There is plenty of material on this subject, but still I could not find what I am doing wrong.

This form is part of a data entry page with several similar forms.

It is neither showing error messages when there are errors nor is it submitting the form when data is fine. By the way, I tested the ajax call before including validation and it is (was) working fine.

I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/H5qH8/2/.

Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.subf').click(function(){
var form_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
var i = form_id.slice(4);
var code = form_id.slice(0,4);
var form_id = "#" + form_id;
var str = $(form_id).serialize();

 $(form_id).validate({
        rules: {
            brand_id: {required: true},
            segment_id: {required: true},
            model: {required: true,maxlength: 25},
            message: {required: true,minlength: 1}
        },
        messages: {brand_id: {required:"Please input brand."},
            segment_id: {required: "Please input segment"},
            model: {required: "Please input model",maxlenght:"Input exceed size=25 characters"},
            message: {required: "What did you want to say?",minlength: "Please complete your thoughts, then submit." }
        },
         errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
            wrapper: "li",
        submitHandler: function(form) {
               $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url: "dataentry2.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType:"html",
                data: 'code='+code+'&'+str,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#" + code + "_id" + i).html(data);
                    },
                });
        }

    }); 

});
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<form class="display" id="mode9">

<select id="mod_brand" class="models" name="brand_id" value="">
<option value="">Brand</option>
<option value= "8" > BMW </option>
<option value= "16" > Citroen </option>
<option value= "17" > Dacia </option>
<option value= "24" > Ford </option>
......
</select>

<select id="mod_seg" class="models" name="segment_id" value="">
<option value="">Segment</option>
<option value= "1" > mini citadines </option>
<option value= "2" > citadines </option>
<option value= "3" > petits monospaces </option>
....
</select>
<input type="text" class="models" name="model" value=""  />

<button id="submodel9" class="subf" type="button" >Submit </button>
</form>
      <ul id="messageBox">
    <li>    
   error message should go here!!
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just realized that jsfiddle does not seem to have the plug-in. I am not sure how it works to have it there. Checking...

Comment: The first (of several) issues is that you aren't actually submitting the form by pushing that button - it's a button, not a "submit" (type="submit") button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To both eliminate the unnecessary `click` handler while also keeping your custom code, use a jQuery `.each()` instead.  It may seem like overkill, but if you're going to have multiple forms on the same page, it's mandatory in order for this plugin to get properly initialized on all of them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.subf').each(function () {
        var form_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var i = form_id.slice(4);
        var code = form_id.slice(0, 4);
        var form_id = "#" + form_id;
        var str = $(form_id).serialize();

        $(form_id).validate({
            rules: {
                brand_id: {
                    required: true
                },
                segment_id: {
                    required: true
                },
                model: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 25
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                }
            },
            messages: {
                brand_id: {
                    required: "Please input brand."
                },
                segment_id: {
                    required: "Please input segment"
                },
                model: {
                    required: "Please input model",
                    maxlenght: "Input exceed size=25 characters"
                },
                message: {
                    required: "What did you want to say?",
                    minlength: "Please complete your thoughts, then submit."
                }
            },
            errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
            wrapper: "li",
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    url: "dataentry2.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: 'code=' + code + '&' + str,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#" + code + "_id" + i).html(data);
                    },
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/H5qH8/4/

Comment: Thanks Sparky, particularly for keeping with original intention of the script. In any case, this does not submit to the 'dataentry2.php' file. I can see the serialized data being passed on on the address bar of the browser(where you would normally see GET data being passed). It does not pass the 'code' variable at all. And it certainly does not reach the php destination. I placed a var_dump on $_REQUEST but it is not kicked back to origin. Can't see data being passed on Firebug console, either.It is a bit maddening how this plug-in gets a perfectly good tool as the ajax call and complicates it

Comment: @BernardA,  did you include the `ajaxSubmit` plugin?  Although in this case a simple jQuery `.ajax()` should be enough.   In other words, the problem is no longer with the `.validate()` function.

Comment: Also, as shown in my jsFiddle, you need a `type="submit"` button within the form in order for the `submitHandler` callback to get fired.

Comment: Sparky. First I re-tried the ajax call with my set up w/o form validate and it works ( with button, type button). Did add jquery.form.min.js ( I believe that's what you refer to as ajaxSubmit plugin) for the heck of it and finally changed button to type=submit. Still SAME problem with the submit.

Comment: @BernardA, sometimes it can be tricky getting the Validate plugin to play nice with the Forms plugin (`ajaxSubmit`).  In this case, as you already see, a simple jQuery `.ajax()` is more than adequate.